# Keras/Tensorflow: Training successful on MBP 13" with Theano, but throws ResourceExhaustedError on a powerful computer with TensorFlow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have successfully trained a Keras model on a 13" Macbook Pro with Theano, albeit at a slow speed, but when I train the exact same model with the same data on a more powerful computer (32 GB RAM, 8 GB Nvidia Quadro GPU, 8 CPU cores) with TensorFlow on Ubuntu, the following error occurs:

[image: ResourceExhaustedError]

Here is the script that I use:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution3D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling3D
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.preprocessing.image import random_rotation, random_shift, random_shear, random_zoom
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.utils.io_utils import HDF5Matrix
from pprint import pprint
from random import shuffle
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
K.set_image_dim_ordering("th")

import cv2
import h5py
import json
import os
import sys
import numpy as np


class OpticalSpeechRecognizer(object):
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, frames_per_sequence, samples_generated_per_sample, config_file, training_save_fn, osr_save_fn):
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.frames_per_sequence = frames_per_sequence
        self.samples_generated_per_sample = samples_generated_per_sample
        self.config_file = config_file
        self.training_save_fn = training_save_fn
        self.osr_save_fn = osr_save_fn
        self.osr = None

    def save_osr_model(self):
        """ Save the OSR model to an HDF5 file 
        """
        # delete file if it already exists
        try:
            print "Saved file \"{0}\" already exists! Overwriting previous saved file.\n".format(self.osr_save_fn)
            os.remove(self.osr_save_fn)
        except OSError:
            pass

        print "Saving OSR model to \"{0}\"".format(self.osr_save_fn)
        self.osr.save(self.osr_save_fn)

    def load_osr_model(self):
        """ Load the OSR model from an HDF5 file
        """
        print "Loading OSR model from \"{0}\"".format(self.osr_save_fn)
        self.osr = load_model(self.osr_save_fn)

    def train_osr_model(self):
        """ Train the optical speech recognizer
        """
        print "\nTraining OSR"
        validation_ratio = 0.3
        batch_size = 25
        training_sequence_generator = self.generate_training_sequences(batch_size=batch_size)
        validation_sequence_generator = self.generate_training_sequences(batch_size=batch_size, validation_ratio=validation_ratio)

        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
            sample_count = training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"]
            pbi = ProgressDisplay()
            self.osr.fit_generator(generator=training_sequence_generator,
                                   validation_data=validation_sequence_generator,
                                   samples_per_epoch=sample_count,
                                   nb_val_samples=int(round(validation_ratio*sample_count)),
                                   nb_epoch=10,
                                   max_q_size=1,
                                   verbose=2,
                                   callbacks=[pbi],
                                   class_weight=None,
                                   nb_worker=1)

    def generate_training_sequences(self, batch_size, validation_ratio=0):
        """ Generates training sequences from HDF5 file on demand
        """
        while True:
            with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
                sample_count = int(training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"])
                sample_idxs = range(0, sample_count)
                shuffle(sample_idxs)
                training_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[0:int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count)]
                validation_sample_idxs = sample_idxs[int((1-validation_ratio)*sample_count):]

                # generate sequences for validation
                if validation_ratio:
                    validation_sample_count = len(validation_sample_idxs)
                    batches = int(validation_sample_count/batch_size)
                    remainder_samples = validation_sample_count%batch_size
                    # generate batches of samples
                    for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                        X = training_save_file["X"][validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][validation_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        yield (X, Y)
                    # send remainder samples as one batch, if there are any
                    if remainder_samples:
                        X = training_save_file["X"][validation_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][validation_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        yield (X, Y)

                # generate sequences for training
                else:
                    training_sample_count = len(training_sample_idxs)
                    batches = int(training_sample_count/batch_size)
                    remainder_samples = training_sample_count%batch_size
                    # generate batches of samples
                    for idx in xrange(0, batches):
                        X = training_save_file["X"][training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][training_sample_idxs[idx*batch_size:idx*batch_size+batch_size]]
                        yield (X, Y)
                    # send remainder samples as one batch, if there are any
                    if remainder_samples:
                        X = training_save_file["X"][training_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        Y = training_save_file["Y"][training_sample_idxs[-remainder_samples:]]
                        yield (X, Y)

    def print_osr_summary(self):
        """ Prints a summary representation of the OSR model
        """
        print "\n*** MODEL SUMMARY ***"
        self.osr.summary()

    def generate_osr_model(self):
        """ Builds the optical speech recognizer model
        """
        print "".join(["\nGenerating OSR model\n",
                       "-"*40])
        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "r") as training_save_file:
            class_count = len(training_save_file.attrs["training_classes"].split(","))

        osr = Sequential()
        print " - Adding convolution layers"
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=32,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              input_shape=(1, self.frames_per_sequence, self.rows, self.columns),
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=64,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(Convolution3D(nb_filter=128,
                              kernel_dim1=3,
                              kernel_dim2=3,
                              kernel_dim3=3,
                              border_mode="same",
                              activation="relu"))
        osr.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(3, 3, 3)))
        osr.add(Dropout(0.2))
        osr.add(Flatten())
        print " - Adding fully connected layers"
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=128,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="relu"))
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=128,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="relu"))
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=128,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="relu"))
        osr.add(Dropout(0.2))
        osr.add(Dense(output_dim=class_count,
                      init="normal",
                      activation="softmax"))
        print " - Compiling model"
        optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.002,
                          beta_1=0.9,
                          beta_2=0.999,
                          epsilon=1e-08,
                          schedule_decay=0.004)
        osr.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                    optimizer=optimizer,
                    metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])
        self.osr = osr
        print " * OSR MODEL GENERATED * "

    def process_training_data(self):
        """ Preprocesses training data and saves them into an HDF5 file
        """
        # load training metadata from config file
        training_metadata = {}
        training_classes = []
        with open(self.config_file) as training_config:
            training_metadata = json.load(training_config)
            training_classes = sorted(list(training_metadata.keys()))

            print "".join(["\n",
                           "Found {0} training classes!\n".format(len(training_classes)),
                           "-"*40])
            for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
                print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<30s}".format(class_label, training_class, training_metadata[training_class])
            print ""

        # count number of samples
        sample_count = 0
        sample_count_by_class = [0]*len(training_classes)
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            # get training class sequeunce paths
            training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
            training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                             for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                             if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                 and ".mov" in file_name)]
            # update sample count
            sample_count += len(training_class_sequence_paths)
            sample_count_by_class[class_label] = len(training_class_sequence_paths)

        print "".join(["\n",
                       "Found {0} training samples!\n".format(sample_count),
                       "-"*40])
        for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
            print "{0:<4d} {1:<10s} {2:<6d}".format(class_label, training_class, sample_count_by_class[class_label])
        print ""

        # initialize HDF5 save file, but clear older duplicate first if it exists
        try:
            print "Saved file \"{0}\" already exists! Overwriting previous saved file.\n".format(self.training_save_fn)
            os.remove(self.training_save_fn)
        except OSError:
            pass

        # process and save training data into HDF5 file
        print "Generating {0} samples from {1} samples via data augmentation\n".format(sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample,
                                                                                       sample_count)
        sample_count = sample_count*self.samples_generated_per_sample
        with h5py.File(self.training_save_fn, "w") as training_save_file:
            training_save_file.attrs["training_classes"] = np.string_(",".join(training_classes))
            training_save_file.attrs["sample_count"] = sample_count
            x_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("X", 
                                                                  shape=(sample_count, 1, self.frames_per_sequence, self.rows, self.columns),
                                                                  dtype="f")
            y_training_dataset = training_save_file.create_dataset("Y",
                                                                   shape=(sample_count, len(training_classes)),
                                                                   dtype="i")

            # iterate through each class data
            sample_idx = 0
            for class_label, training_class in enumerate(training_classes):
                # get training class sequeunce paths
                training_class_data_path = training_metadata[training_class]
                training_class_sequence_paths = [os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name)
                                                 for file_name in os.listdir(training_class_data_path)
                                                 if (os.path.isfile(os.path.join(training_class_data_path, file_name))
                                                     and ".mov" in file_name)]
                # iterate through each sequence
                for idx, training_class_sequence_path in enumerate(training_class_sequence_paths):
                    sys.stdout.write("Processing training data for class \"{0}\": {1}/{2} sequences\r"
                                     .format(training_class, idx+1, len(training_class_sequence_paths)))
                    sys.stdout.flush()

                    # accumulate samples and labels
                    samples_batch = self.process_frames(training_class_sequence_path)
                    label = [0]*len(training_classes)
                    label[class_label] = 1

                    for sample in samples_batch:
                        x_training_dataset[sample_idx] = sample
                        y_training_dataset[sample_idx] = label

                        # update sample index
                        sample_idx += 1

                print "\n"

            training_save_file.close()

            print "Training data processed and saved to {0}".format(self.training_save_fn)

    def process_frames(self, video_file_path):
        """ Preprocesses sequence frames
        """
        # haar cascades for localizing oral region
        face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        mouth_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml')

        video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
        success, frame = video.read()

        frames = []
        success = True

        # convert to grayscale, localize oral region, equalize frame dimensions, and accumulate valid frames 
        while success:
          success, frame = video.read()
          if success:
            # convert to grayscale
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # localize single facial region
            faces_coords = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
            if len(faces_coords) == 1:
              face_x, face_y, face_w, face_h = faces_coords[0]
              frame = frame[face_y:face_y + face_h, face_x:face_x + face_w]

              # localize oral region
              mouth_coords = mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
              threshold = 0
              for (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h) in mouth_coords:
                if (mouth_y > threshold):
                    threshold = mouth_y
                    valid_mouth_coords = (mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h)
                else:
                    pass
              mouth_x, mouth_y, mouth_w, mouth_h = valid_mouth_coords
              frame = frame[mouth_y:mouth_y + mouth_h, mouth_x:mouth_x + mouth_w]

              # equalize frame dimensions
              frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.columns, self.rows)).astype('float32')

              # accumulate frames
              frames.append(frame)

            # ignore multiple facial region detections
            else:
                pass

        # equalize sequence lengths 
        if len(frames) < self.frames_per_sequence:
            frames = [frames[0]]*(self.frames_per_sequence - len(frames)) + frames
        frames = np.asarray(frames[0:self.frames_per_sequence])

        # pixel normalizer
        pix_norm = lambda frame: frame / 255.0

        samples_batch = [[map(pix_norm, frames)]]

        # random transformations for data augmentation
        for _ in xrange(0, self.samples_generated_per_sample-1):
            rotated_frames = random_rotation(frames, rg=45)
            shifted_frames = random_shift(rotated_frames, wrg=0.25, hrg=0.25)
            sheared_frames = random_shear(shifted_frames, intensity=0.79)
            zoomed_frames = random_zoom(sheared_frames, zoom_range=(1.25, 1.25))
            samples_batch.append([map(pix_norm, zoomed_frames)])

        return samples_batch

class ProgressDisplay(Callback):
    """ Progress display callback
    """
    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        print "    Batch {0:<4d} => Accuracy: {1:>8.4f} | Loss: {2:>8.4f} | Size: {3:>4d}".format(int(logs["batch"])+1,
                                                                                                  float(logs["categorical_accuracy"]),
                                                                                                  float(logs["loss"]),
                                                                                                  int(logs["size"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Example usage
    osr = OpticalSpeechRecognizer(rows=100, 
                                  columns=150, 
                                  frames_per_sequence=45, 
                                  samples_generated_per_sample=10, 
                                  config_file="training_config.json", 
                                  training_save_fn="training_data.h5", 
                                  osr_save_fn="osr_model.h5")
    osr.process_training_data()
    osr.generate_osr_model()
    osr.print_osr_summary()
    osr.train_osr_model()
    osr.save_osr_model()
    osr.load_osr_model()
```

Comment: Resource exhausted could be related to running out of file descriptors. That can be changed in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or `/etc/security/limits.conf`. If appropriate, you could try to run as root as a quick check.

Comment: @drpng Can you expound on that with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, the problem seems to be a TensorFlow issue. For me, the solution was to switch the backend to Theano. To switch the Keras backend, perform the following steps:

1. Find the Keras configuration file

   ~/.keras/keras.json
2. Change the value of the backend field and, optionally, the ordering field

   {
       "image_dim_ordering": "th",
       "epsilon": 1e-07,
       "floatx": "float32",
       "backend": "theano"
   }